# Can OPENSSL BIO be used within a C program that uses OPENSSL EVP to encrypt/decrypt a file?

Tags: c, openssl, encryption-symmetric, evp-cipher

Reading the openssl documentation I realized that you can use the openssl EVP API, to replicate what you can do with the commands:

$ openssl aes-256-cbc -in text.txt -out text_out.txt -e -kfile encryption.key

Through this C programm:

```
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    /*
     * Set up the key and iv. Do I need to say to not hard code these in a
     * real application? :-)
     */

    /* A 256 bit key */
    unsigned char *key = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
                           0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35,
                           0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33,
                           0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31
                         };

    /* A 128 bit IV */
    unsigned char *iv = { 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37,
                          0x38, 0x39, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35
                        };

    /* Message to be encrypted */
    unsigned char *plaintext =
        (unsigned char *)"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    /*
     * Buffer for ciphertext. Ensure the buffer is long enough for the
     * ciphertext which may be longer than the plaintext, depending on the
     * algorithm and mode.
     */
    unsigned char ciphertext[128];

    /* Buffer for the decrypted text */
    unsigned char decryptedtext[128];

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    /* Encrypt the plaintext */
    ciphertext_len = encrypt (plaintext, strlen ((char *)plaintext), key, iv,
                              ciphertext);

    /* Do something useful with the ciphertext here */
    printf("Ciphertext is:\n");
    BIO_dump_fp (stdout, (const char *)ciphertext, ciphertext_len);

    /* Decrypt the ciphertext */
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt(ciphertext, ciphertext_len, key, iv,
                                decryptedtext);

    /* Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text */
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    /* Show the decrypted text */
    printf("Decrypted text is:\n");
    printf("%s\n", decryptedtext);


    return 0;
}
```

and this for encryption function:

```
int encrypt(unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *ciphertext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int ciphertext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the encryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be encrypted, and obtain the encrypted output.
     * EVP_EncryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the encryption. Further ciphertext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, ciphertext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    ciphertext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ciphertext_len;
}
```

and decryption function:

```
int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key,
            unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    /* Create and initialise the context */
    if(!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Initialise the decryption operation. IMPORTANT - ensure you use a key
     * and IV size appropriate for your cipher
     * In this example we are using 256 bit AES (i.e. a 256 bit key). The
     * IV size for *most* modes is the same as the block size. For AES this
     * is 128 bits
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();

    /*
     * Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.
     * EVP_DecryptUpdate can be called multiple times if necessary.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    /*
     * Finalise the decryption. Further plaintext bytes may be written at
     * this stage.
     */
    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    /* Clean up */
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}
```

Now I wonder, is it possible to integrate the tools provided by openssl BIO into a similar program?
And if this is possible, what are the advantages compared to doing an encryption and decryption using only openssl ENV?
Are there any cases where it is convenient to treat files with the tools provided by BIO instead of treating them as normal files?

Answer (score 1):

> can you integrate the tools provided by openssl BIO into a similar program?

Yes, that's the big benefit of having separate libraries. Libraries like OpenSSL can be reused in millions of projects without much effort.

> And if this is possible, what are the benefits?

The biggest benefit is that you will not have to write a compatible set of functions yourself. A library such as OpenSSL is also well tested.

Note: If a library such as OpenSSL has vulnerabilities, you'll share those vulnerabilities with the the rest of the world that also uses OpenSSL. That's the downside.